# Data from gpx file wont change in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I don't get it. I try to add a new layer several times via python console, but the data from the GPX file stays the same even though i change the underlying Waypoints.gpx file between every script execution. After some time, the change gets noticed and with the next script execution, and the "new" data gets imported. Is there a cache or something? How to disable it? I also tried to use different layer name and pressed the refresh button on the data source, no change.

QGIS 3.26.1-Buenos Aires

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
file = '/path/to/file/Waypoints.gpx?type=waypoint'
layer = QgsVectorLayer(file, 'new layer', 'gpx')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: yes i did .. no change ... i'll edit my code

Comment: I don't think it's a display issue since i removed 1 of 4 waypoints from the GPX file, but also the attribute table still has 4

Comment: I also printed the file in the same script and the change was printed .. i don't know ... face one weird problem after another with QGIS

Comment: Weird ... if i "Change data source ..." to exactly the same file, the change will then be recognized ... but why not when adding it via console?

Comment: There is `setDataSource()` method of `QgsMapLayer` class. https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#ac35d3cb171b46bdbed6c4a96e186c508 You could try using that instead of reloading a new `QgsVectorLayer` object.